# Asking for help from senior or anyone is it such a big issue and geting fired because of it

Tags: software-industry, training, knowledge-transfer

I am currently working as a software engineer and I am a trainee. The problem is I was working on Android development, and my work got delayed and the guy who I was reporting is not familiar in Android.

So when I used to ask for his help, he couldn't help me  and when I use to ask help from someone else the hr refused to let them help me, they use to say this is not a school or a teaching place and if the senior help you they won't be able to do their work.

So my work got delayed and the removed me from Android and now they are threatening to firing me for slow working.

So here is my question

1. Was it such a big issue to help someone who is asking for help?
2. What should I do now as it seems unfair for me getting fired?

Comment: man you shoulda hit stackoverflow instead of your coworkers!   Although if you are really a "trainee" it's pretty messed up to say it's not a teaching place...?  spend your days learning online then show them you are a master of android.

Comment: A company that says their seniors don't have time to help trainees should only hire senior developers, imho. Sounds to me like they want to pay low wages but still get senior engineer performance.

Comment: @user3114091 : Which company is it?.. :)

Comment: Agnicent and I haven't studied android before intact now I want to study android even more since it the first time studding it got me interested . It them who assigned me to android because at that time i had no work and none in my company haven't done it before also .

Comment: An important aspect imo: when they hired you, did you have a talk with them in which they said that you are forbidden to ask senior developers for help ? If no, then I think it's completely unreasonable to fire you for this (or even threat to fire you). If yes, then... well, it's questionable.

Comment: Of course not and now there attitude is  let  him do what he wants we will simply ignore him

Answer (score 5):

You getting mentoring from a senior developer isn't free for the company. While they teach you, they can't work on their own project. This means less hours to bill on a client or less hours to work on an important and lucrative project. That means there is an interest in keeping the senior developers free from any distraction so they can focus all of their time on their projects.

But on the other hand, when a company hires trainees, they need to be aware that most won't be able to cover their own cost at first. Even when they aren't paid well. They usually need some training to become productive. This training process can be vastly accelerated through intensive mentoring by senior developers. So there is an interest to make senior-developers available to the trainees.

As you see, these two interests clash. Every company has to decide for itself how to balance them. Obviously your company has decided to prioritize the first. Your options now are:

- Convince them that you could become a productive employee with adequate mentoring and training.
- Become an autodidact and acquire the required knowledge on your own. Don't be afraid to search on the Internet for help. Stackoverflow is a great resource, for example.
- Search for a new job which better fits your skillset or where it is clear upfront that you will receive training. This could be a job in your current company or in another one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd question what level of work did you do before asking for help and after asking for help. If you figure that someone has to come give you the answer that could be seen as a problem since sometimes in software development developers have to solve their own problems.

As for what to do now, depending on your country there could be various labor laws to research as well as consider if this kind of work is a good fit where you may have to figure things out on your own and help isn't always available exactly when you need it.